# $.ajax URL does not accept values when inside a function

Tags: function, jquery

I am using several $.ajax calls to next and previous pages. So I thought using a function would simplify it. I placed the $.ajax function inside another function with an argument to pass desired URL. While URL is being passed, it is not accepted as URL in $.ajax. Here's my function:

```
function show_slide(link) { 
    if (link!=null) {
        alert(link); //this shows correct URL
        $.ajax({
        url: link, // this does not work
        success: function(data) { ... ... }
        }); 
    }
}
```

The above function is outside the $(document).ready(). Can someone figure out what's the problem?

Comment: are you sure you're passing the correct url to `show_slide`?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I have used alert() to double check.

Answer (score 1):

Please use chrome developer tools and shows what the network call and response was. The problem maybe is because you're trying to call an url from another site. The cross-domain calls in javascript is prohibited for security reasons.

I wrote your function for testing and it appears to work without problems. When I call http://www.google.com (for example) the network call is bloqued.

Answer (score 0):

It works if ajax call is within the domain, check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6kvNd/7/) out.